# In the Chrome developer panel, is there a keyboard shortcut for the element selector?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In the Chrome developer panel, this tool...

[image]

lets you select elements and go directly to them in the DOM view, and see their CSS attributes.

Safari has the same tool.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to activate that tool (once you have the panel open)?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

To open / switch from inspect element mode and browser window, you can do:

- On Mac - <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
- On Windows / Linux - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> OR <kbd>F12</kbd>

For more useful keyboard shortcuts, refer to the [developer tools documentation](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/shortcuts).

Comment: @SimpleCoder In fact, it **is** listed in the documentation, see https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/shortcuts.

Comment: I meant the Shortcuts panel under options.

Comment: That shortcut also works in `linux` version as well.

Comment: Maybe someone knows possibility to be able to inspect element right after pressing Ctrl + Shift + C? When Web developer tools are not shown and you press this shortcut, elements selector is not selected automatically - you must press it second time or even third. That seriously affects productivity if you are working on 4 tabs, changing them, opening and closing web developer tools.. It's annoying - I came from Opera developer tools and nothing was better for now.

Comment: `Ctrl + Shift + C` is the better shortcut because it selects the element mouse-overed immediately. With F12 you need another mouse click. My gosh, this shortcut is such a time saver!

Answer (score 6):

The shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> ([source](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=29532#c15)).

You can also right click any element in a web page and click `Inspect element`.

Answer (score 4):

Ctrl + Shift + C for linux as well.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows & Linux, to bring up the "Inspect element" pane at the bottom:

- You can either use: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- OR you can use: <kbd>F12</kbd>

While you can usually right click elements in a web page and click `Inspect element`, it's useful to know these keyboard shortcuts for when a page has JavaScript to disable right-click in that page.

Answer (score 2):

On a Mac you can use <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

This is what works for me.

Here's a resource where you can find all these shortcuts 
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/shortcuts

Comment: where did u find this?

Comment: Can't remember where I did :) I've updated my answer with a link to shortcuts for different devices and operating systems.